# In Rust I want to assign a given value to all elements of nested vectors

Tags: rust, vector

I am trying to build a function similar to np.zeros from Python for Rust.

I would like to do something like:

```
trait VectorHelper {
  fn fill_with<A>(&mut self, value: A) -> &mut Self;
}
impl<T: VectorHelper> VectorHelper for Vec<T> {
  fn fill_with<A>(&mut self, value: A) -> &mut Self {
    for elem in self.iter() {
      if elem.is_vec() {
        elem.fill_with(value);
      } else {
        *elem = value;
      }
    }
    self
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to get this to work, because there is no general conversion for A to T.
What can I do to make the compiler accept this assignment: "*elem = value"?

Comment: You need specialization for that to work, so it cannot be done on stable.

Comment: I think that even on nightly this cannot be done today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the exact implementation like you want it isn't possible you can still handle all the additional layers but the first by a blanket implementation:

```rust
impl<V: Clone, T: VectorHelper<V>> VectorHelper<V> for Vec<T> {
  fn fill_with(&mut self, value: V) -> &mut Self {
    for elem in &mut *self {
        elem.fill_with(value.clone());
    }
    self
  }
}
```

Then for each base type you can implement the trait once (possibly by a macro to reduce duplication):

```rust
macro_rules! impl_vector_helper {
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl VectorHelper<$t> for Vec<$t> {
            fn fill_with(&mut self, value: $t) -> &mut Self {
                self.fill(value);
                self
            }
        }
    };
    ($($t:ty),* $(,)?) => {
        $(impl_vector_helper!{$t})*
    };
}

impl_vector_helper! {
    u8, u16, u32, u64,
    i8, i16, i32, i64,
    f32, f64,
    &'static str,
}
```

You just have to move the generic from the function to the trait:

```rust
trait VectorHelper<V> {
    fn fill_with(&mut self, value: V) -> &mut Self;
}
```

Comment: I didn't include `usize` in the `impl_vector_helper!` call and that's not valid Rust so no but it [will work if you add the missing `()` and an implementation for `usize`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a24d243c51bc0b8b85edade959573e8). For the future, the compiler and just trying is probably faster at telling you answers to such questions.

Comment: Wow! Just tried it with u8. The problem really was usize. Ok Now I have something to study

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that there is no solution how I intended it, I have to stick with my workaround, until there is a proper solution.
But hopefully there are better ways to do this.
I would be pleased to learn about them.

```
trait VectorHelper {
  fn fill_with(&mut self, value: f64) -> &mut Self;
}
impl VectorHelper for Vec<f64> {
  fn fill_with(&mut self, value:f64) -> &mut Self {
    for elem in self.iter_mut() {
      *elem = value;
    }
    self
  }
}
impl VectorHelper for Vec<Vec<f64>> {
  fn fill_with(&mut self, value:f64) -> &mut Self {
    for k in self.iter_mut() {
      for j in k.iter_mut() {
        *j = value;
      }
    }
    self
  }
}
impl VectorHelper for Vec<Vec<Vec<f64>>> {
  fn fill_with(&mut self, value:f64) -> &mut Self {
    for k in self.iter_mut() {
      for j in k.iter_mut() {
        for l in j.iter_mut() {
          *l = value;
        }
      }
    }
    self
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the trait to something like

```rust
trait VectorHelper<T> {
    fn fill_with<A>(&mut self, value: A) -> &mut Self
    where
        A: Into<T>;
}
```

and then you could implement it as

```rust
impl<T> VectorHelper<T> for Vec<T>
where
    T: VectorHelper<T>,
{
    fn fill_with<A>(&mut self, value: A) -> &mut Self
    where
        A: Into<T>,
    {
        for elem in self.iter() {
            if elem.is_vec() {
                elem.fill_with(value);
            } else {
                *elem = value.into();
            }
        }
        self
    }
}
```

This code, however, will not work for several other reasons, and I assume this was only used as an example to ask for a specific part that troubles you (the conversion). If not, you have two options:

## 1. Manually descend to the bottom level of your vectors and fill them with desired value:

```rust
let mut v1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
v1.fill(0);
assert_eq!(v1, vec![0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

let mut v2 = vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4, 5]];
v2.iter_mut().for_each(|v| v.fill(0));
assert_eq!(v2, vec![vec![0, 0], vec![0, 0, 0]]);

let mut v3 = vec![vec![vec![1], vec![2]], vec![vec![3, 4], vec![5]]];
v3.iter_mut()
    .for_each(|v| v.iter_mut().for_each(|v| v.fill(0)));
assert_eq!(v3, vec![vec![vec![0], vec![0]], vec![vec![0, 0], vec![0]]]);
```

## 2. Implement custom NestedVec

```rust
enum NestedVec<T> {
    Vec(Vec<NestedVec<T>>),
    Val(T),
}

impl<T> NestedVec<T> {
    fn fill<A>(&mut self, value: A)
    where
        A: Clone + Into<T>,
    {
        match self {
            Self::Vec(vec) => vec.iter_mut().for_each(|elem| elem.fill(value.clone())),
            Self::Val(val) => {
                *val = value.into();
            }
        }
    }
}

let mut nested = NestedVec::Vec(vec![
    NestedVec::Vec(vec![
        NestedVec::Val(2),
        NestedVec::Vec(vec![NestedVec::Val(3), NestedVec::Val(4)]),
    ]),
    NestedVec::Val(5),
]);

nested.fill(0);
```

You'll probably want to also implement helper functions, traits and/or macros for constructing this struct, inserting elements, etc.

Comment: No, the code was meant to work. I originally come from programming pascal and javascript and because pascal does not allow cross-platform programming and javascript's solutions for "stand alone applications" are at least somehow crude, I am trying to get my problems solved with rust.
The point here is, that it is no problem to get recursive functions to work with the former languages. 
I really wanted to make the differentiation to call the function again, as long as the parameter is a vector, and give it a new value if not.

Comment: Your nested vec solution seems to work but seems not be applicable for existing array like structures. Or could you provide a conversion method from vec to nested vec and vice versa?

Comment: @Mecki This isn't how rust works. Rust takes pride in forcing coders to be explicit. You can't just pass anything to the function and check at runtime which type it is. I mean you could, but it is discouraged, and in this case maybe even impossible. If it comes to this, it's usually not that language is bad, but the code is bad and you should rethink and find better approach. How could compiler know whether or not you are trying to assign a number where vector is expected? You could take a look at [Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) trait and see if it helps you.

Comment: @Mecki And for the conversion to `NestedVec` you would need to write conversions from all possible levels, i.e. `From<Vec<T>>`, `From<Vec<Vec<T>>>`, etc. And it goes only one way, you can't convert `NestedVec<T>` to `Vec<T>` always, because vectors require certain condition, and that is that all the elements are of the same type, which means you can't have both vectors and values on the same level.